# Expo: My app got rejected from google play about location policy

Tags: android, react-native, permissions, google-play, expo

My app contains a plugin for maps and it doesn't require user location permission. However, Google Play rejected it because my app isn't compliant with the Location permissions policy.

The following is the code I write, which doesn't require user location.

```
  import MapView from 'react-native-maps';

  <MapView region={this.state.mapRegion}>
    <MapView.Marker coordinate={this.state.marker} />
  </MapView>
```

Is there anyone who can provide advice? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Please add permissions=[] in your App.json (in android) and try again.

```
"android": {
    "permissions": [],
    "package": "com.xxxxxx.xxxxx"
      
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set app permission required in app.json
If permission is not defined in app.json, the default permission will include all except ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION

```
{
    "android": {
        "package": "xxx.yyy.zzz"
    }
}
```

If an empty array is provided, only these permissions will be included:
• receive data from Internet (fetch)
• view network connections (expo-network)
• full network access (expo-network/fetch)
• change your audio settings (expo-av)
• prevent device from sleeping (expo-keep-awake)

```
{
    "android": {
        "package": "xxx.yyy.zzz",
        "permissions": []
    }
}
```

If you don't want to include all permissions, you can customize in the `permissions` field

```
{
    "android": {
        "package": "xxx.yyy.zzz",
        "permissions": [
            "CAMERA",
            "RECORD_AUDIO",
            "READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE",
            "WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"
        ]
    }
}
```

ref: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/config/app/#permissions